# Как сделать чтоб значения из запроса попадали в поле для ввода?

Tags: java, html, jsp

здравствуйте
есть запрос с параметрами

```
http://localhost:8080/Example/exampl?x=Hello&y=World
```

как сделать чтоб значения из запроса попадали в поле для ввода?

Comment: при открытии страницы сразу были в полях, как понимаю?

Comment: @SeniorAutomator да,чтоб были в полях

Comment: Я бы нарисовал свой servlet с этими параметрами, при загрузке страницы,  получая эти параметры,  поставлял бы в поля

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EL expression`:

```
${param.x}
```

`Java`:

```
<%= request.getParameter("x") %>
```

`URI`:

```
uri.getQuery()
```